# prototype selector returns object

Tags: prototypejs, selector

so I have a div:

```
<div id="divId">some content in here</div>
```

And I want to get the content of this div, so I do what I always do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        var divContent = $('divId');
        console.log(divContent);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

But instead of having the content of the div logged out in firebug, I get `[object HTMLDivElement]`.
What am I missing?

nb: protoype library is loaded in the head of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I was missing `.innerHTML`:

```
<div id="divId">some content in here</div>
```

And I want to get the content of this div, so I do what I always do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        var divContent = $('divId').innerHTML;
        console.log(divContent);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```